# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'draw')

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am writting a JavaScript game Pacman. Butr instead of drawing canvas, this error is shown and nothing happens.

```
function pause() {
    return !pacman.madeFirstMove || gameOver || gameWin;
  }

function gameLoop(){
    titleMap.draw(ctx);
    drawGameEnd();
    pacman.draw(ctx, pause(), enemies); //**shows the error is here **
    enemies.forEach((enemy) => enemy.draw(ctx, pause(), pacman));
    checkGameOver();
    checkGameWin();
}
```

Here is the implementation of the draw function:

```
 draw(ctx, pause, enemies) {
    if (!pause) {
      this.#move();
      this.#animate();
    }
    this.#eatDot();
    this.#eatPowerDot();
    this.#eatGhost(enemies);

    const size = this.tileSize / 2;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.x + size, this.y + size);
    ctx.rotate((this.pacmanRotation * 90 * Math.PI) / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(
      this.pacmanImages[this.pacmanImageIndex],
      -size,
      -size,
      this.tileSize,
      this.tileSize
    );

    ctx.restore();

     ctx.drawImage(
       this.pacmanImages[this.pacmanImageIndex],
       this.x,
       this.y,
      this.tileSize,
       this.tileSize
     );
  }
```

```
The pacman is defined like this:

const titleSize=32;
const velocity=2;
const canvas= document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const titleMap= new TheMap(titleSize);

const pacman = titleMap.getPacman(velocity);
```

Please, let me know if you need more about the code to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Some helpful links : https://www.w3schools.com/js/ https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-scope/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript

Comment: Errors have useful messages that usually tell exactly what went wrong